# jQuery - start new circles expansion from the same position as the old ones

Tags: jquery, css

I have a circle animation, where circles of a dark blue color appear at random places and expand. When these expanding circles have covered more tha half the screen approximately, the color of the expanding circles changes to a lighter blue. You can see the animation here: https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/spotify-circle-animation/

After a while the animation goes a bit haywire with different color circles appearing randomly. To get a smooth animation, when the colors are swapped, I figured that the newer circles should appear in the same place as the old ones.

This is the code I have till now:

CSS:

```
.initial-div {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.position-div{
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: none;
}

.section {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.animate {
    -webkit-animation: expand 100s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';

        var circles = [];
        function makeDiv(color){
            var divsize = 1000;
            $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass('initial-div').css({
                'background-color': color
            });

            var posx = (Math.random() * ($('.section').width()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
            var posy = (Math.random() * ($('.section').height()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed();
            var circle = {
                x : posx,
                y : posy
            };
            $newdiv.addClass('position-div').css({
                'left':posx+'px',
                'top':posy+'px'
            }).appendTo("#fullpage").addClass('animate').css({'display':'block'}).one(animationEnd,function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){


                var colorArray = ['#11256c','#24ccdf'];
                var i= 0,flag=0;
                var color = colorArray[i];
                setInterval(function(){
                    flag++;
                    makeDiv(color);
                    if (flag == 10){
                        color = colorArray[i];
                        i++;
                        if (i == 2) {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        flag=0;
                    }
                },2000);

        });
```

I think we need an array of objects with the x and y positions of the old circles, but I am not sure how to fit in the function. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this, just populate the circles array and for each iteration take the same coordinates

```
  var circles = [];

  function makeDiv(color, index){

      $newdiv = $('<div/>').addClass('initial-div').css({
          'background-color': color
      });

      // access the coordinates with index so for each iteration they will be the same
      $newdiv.addClass('position-div').css({
          'left':circles[index].x+'px',
          'top':circles[index].y+'px'
      }).appendTo("#fullpage").addClass('animate').css({'display':'block'}).one(animationEnd,function(){
          $(this).remove();
      });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    // populate your circles array with randomm coordinates
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
      var divsize = 1000;
      var circle = {
          x : (Math.random() * ($('.section').width()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed(),
          y : (Math.random() * ($('.section').height()) - (divsize / 2)).toFixed()
      };
      circles.push(circle);
    }

    var colorArray = ['#11256c','#24ccdf'];
    var i= 0,flag=0;
    var color = colorArray[i];
    setInterval(function(){
        // pass the index (flag)
        makeDiv(color, flag);
        flag++;
        if (flag == 10){
            color = colorArray[i];
            i++;
            if (i == 2) {
                i = 0;
            }
            flag=0;
        }
    },2000);

  });
```

That would be the answer to your question But i dont think this will smaller the performance issues, you rather need to remove circles after some iterations